# Django Database routers Failover Scenario

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, high-availability, failover

based on django Documentation about databases routers 
[Databases Routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)
you can specify Writing DBS, And Reading,

how can i check if this this DB is online then return it,

for example
i have 2 Masters DB and 2 Slaves DB,

for reading purpose i want to check if Slave1 is online then return it, otherwise return Slave2 
same for writing Master1 and Master2

Comment: I wouldn't use django routers for this. Instead, set up this kind of failover within your database cluster.

Comment: i failed to find a solution for mysql, i am using mysql + tungsten for replication any idea?

Comment: did you manage to solve?